# Tried to replace $_GET with $_POST, but now it won't display or update

Tags: php, html

I tried to retype a code of my groupmate, because the 'textarea' in here is going to be bombarded by a whole lot of string and the problem is that the request URI is too long. So I tried to change of all the $_GET to $_POST, because it won't be posted in the URL.

But the problem is that it won't display the input 'text' and 'textarea' in the isset. I don't know whether it's the isset that is the problem or the or the $_POST, but when I return it back to $_GET it works.

PHP Code for displaying the chapters to be updated and the update function.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$id = $_POST['cid'];
$title = $_POST['ctitle'];
$body = $_POST['cbody'];
$result = $db->query("UPDATE chapter set chapter_title='$title',     chapter_body='$body' where chapter_id='$id'");
}
$result = $db->query("select * from chapter");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$update = 'chapterid';
echo "<li id='button' class='btn' ><b id='shadow'><a href='chapter1.php?update={$row['chapter_id']}'>{$row['chapter_title']}</b></a></li></button>";
}
?>
```

PHP code for displaying the input 'text' and 'textarea'.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
$update = $_POST['update'];
$result1 = $db->query("select * from chapter where chapter_id=$update");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
echo "<center>";
echo "<form class='form' method='POST'>";
echo "<h2>Update Form</h2>";
echo "<hr/>";
echo"<input class='input' type='hidden' name='cid' value='{$row1['chapter_id']}'/>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<label>" . "Chapter Title:" . "</label>" . "<br />";
echo"<input class='input' type='text' name='ctitle' value='{$row1['chapter_title']}' />";
echo "<br />";
echo "<label>" . "Chapter Body:" . "</label>" . "<br />";
echo "<textarea rows='15' cols='95' name='cbody'>{$row1['chapter_body']}";
echo "</textarea>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<input class='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='update' />";
echo "</form>";
echo "</center>";
}
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo '<div class="form" id="form3"><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<Span>Data Updated Successfuly......!!</span></div>';
}
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

</div><?php
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Have you changed form's method to GET?

Comment: Does it make the submission via POST? You are open to SQL injections with this code. Don't use `query` use `prepare` and `execute` and separate the user input from your query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
```

This line should stay $_GET['update'], because "update" is not part of you form, but part of the url:

```
<a href='chapter1.php?update={$row['chapter_id']}'
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me this two errors:

    Notice: Undefined index: update in C:\xampp\htdocs\purehtml\chapter1.php on line 111

    Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\purehtml\chapter1.php on line 113

Comment: Read Alan Machado comment also.

Comment: Also I wouldn't say to user that update is correct just by checking `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: sorry, I commented before I refreshed and read it. The problem that arises with that is that it won't execute this code.

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo '<div class="form" id="form3"><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <Span>Data Updated Successfuly......!!</span></div>';

    }

    ?>

meaning that it didn't update.

EDIT: It did update, but it won't still execute the last echo.

Comment: @MinatoArisato Update the question to your current code.